# if $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ converges but $\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i)^2$ diverges, does that mean that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ is conditionally

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

I don't think this is true, but cannot find an example to disproof it.
Either that or i need to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|$ diverges, which I am unclear how to approach the proof.

Comment: To get the sum of the $a_n$ terms to converge, you must have $a_n\to 0$.  How then does $|a_n|$ compare with $(a_n)^2$ whose sum is hypothesized to diverge?

Comment: Minor notation quibble: $\sum_{i=1}^n$ denotes a *finite* sum. You want $\sum_{i=1}^\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true. That's so because, if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ was absolutely convergent, then we would have $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ and therefore $a_n^{\,2}\leqslant |a_n|$ if $n$ is large enough. So, by the comparison test (this is where absolute convergence is used), $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{\,2}$ would converge too.

Comment: Yup, you blew my cover.  I do hope the OP was able to figure out my comment beforehand.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Sorry about that. I only saw your comment after posting my answer.

Comment: It should be $a_n^2 \le |a_n|$, shouldn't it?

Comment: Corrected, now.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Thank you.

Comment: I didn't have this approach in mind but its brilliant, Thank you for the help!